# How can I understand the meaning of "Point of Instantiation"

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, instantiation

I am now learning some meta-programming skills from [non-constant-constant-expressions](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions), and I feel confused about "Point of Instantiation". The author says

> Whenever a template specialization is referenced in a context that requires instantiation, that context gives birth to a "point of instantiation" (which effectively denotes a location where the compiler is allowed to generate code for the referenced template specialization).
>
> If a template specialization X is referenced in a context that depends on a template-parameter of some surrounding template Y, the given point of instantation depends on the point of instantation of Y.
>
> - If X is a function template specialization, the point of instantiation is that of Y.
> - If X is a class template specialization, the point of instantiation is immediately before the point of instantiation of Y.
>
> Otherwise, the given point of instantiation is tied to the location of the namespace scope declaration/definition (D) which contains the statement referring to X.
>
> - If X is a function template specialization, the point of instantiation is immediately after D.
> - If X is a class template specialization, the point of instantiation is immediately before D.

I don't know what is "a template specialization X is referenced in a context that depends on a template-parameter of some surrounding template Y", does he mean

```
template<typename T>
class Y{
    template<typename U1> void X1(){...};
    template<typename U2> class X2{...};
}
```

Consider `Y<int>::X1<int>(...)`, `X1` and `Y` instantiate at the same time.

Consider `Y<int>::X2<int>{...}`, `X2` first `Y` second.

Comment: It means "when the template is used and a type crystallised". E.g. `std::vector<double>` is a "point of instantiation" of the template `std::vector<...>`.

Comment: There is no template specialization in your example.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, you are right, I've tried to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that, given

```
template<class> class A {};
template<class T> void f(T) {}
template<class T> void g() {f(A<T>{});}
```

the point of instantiation of (say) `A<int>` is immediately before that shared by `f<int>` and `g<int>`.  (Remember that function (but not class) templates can have [more than one point of instantiation](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#8) in a translation unit.)

Comment: In this case, A is to X what g is to Y because X is referenced in g, so it instantiates immediately before g. f and g instantiate at the same time point because the "Otherwise" rule. Is it true?

Comment: @calvin: Yes about `A`, but `f` and `A` is covered by the very first bullet.  I obscured that by forgetting to use it, sorry.